# WSAECONNABORTED (10053) error received while calling send command after fixed iterations

Tags: sockets

I'm also facing some issue where a server sends data to client and client sends back the acknowledgement. But after certain iterations the socket is aborted and I'm getting WSAECONNABORTED (10053) while sending the acknowledgement back to server.

I'm on win7 64-bit machine.

### Server code(this is perl code):

```
sub Send_Msg_to_SourceSelector

{

(my $msg)=@_;

    my $msg_len = length("$msg")+1;
    print "the message length is: $msg_len\n\n";
    PrintLogFile(1, ">> $CurrentTime >> The message length is : $msg_len <<<<\n\n");
    print "the SOCK1 is: SOCK\n\n";
    PrintLogFile(1, ">> $CurrentTime >> The sent message is : $msg <<<<\n\n");
    send $SOCK,$msg,$msg_len;
    print "the SOCK2 is: $SOCK\n\n";
    recv $SOCK,my $awk,3,0;
    PrintLogFile(1, ">> $CurrentTime >> The acknowledgement received is : $awk <<<<\n\n");
    print "the SOCK3 is: $SOCK\n\n";
}
```

## Client code (this is in C...executable generated in visual studio 2013):

```
void RecvDataFromSequencer(SOCKET sock, FILE *Log)
{
    char n,buffer[2000];

    while(!FlagTestExecutionCompleted)
    {
        memset (buffer , 0 , 2000);
        printf("The address of buffer before is: %d\n", buffer);
        n = recv(sock,buffer,2000,0); //blocking call
        printf("The address of buffer after is: %d\n", buffer);
        printf("in recv func: %x\n", Log);
        //printlogfile(Log, buffer);
        fprintf(Log,"%s%s",buffer,"\n");
        fprintf(Log,"%d%s",n,"\n");
        fprintf(Log,"%s%d%s","FlagTestExecutionCompleted is ==> ",FlagTestExecutionCompleted,"\n");
        fflush(Log);
        if (n == -1)
        {
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            fprintf(Log,"%s%s",WSAGetLastError(),"\n");
            error("ERROR reading from STATS");
            fprintf(Log,"%s%s","ERROR reading from STATS","\n");
            fflush(Log);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nMessage from STATS: %s\n",buffer);
            strcpy(line_tcfile,buffer);
            if(strstr(line_tcfile,"SessionCompleted"))
            {
                printf("\n End of Test Session");
                FlagTestExecutionCompleted=1;
            }
            FlagNewTestCaseRecieved = 1;
        }

        //Send acknowledgement
        Sleep(1000);
        **n = send(sock,"ACK",3,0);
        if (n == -1)
        {
            fprintf(Log,"%s%d%s","in send command FlagTestExecutionCompleted is ==> ",FlagTestExecutionCompleted,"\n");
            printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            fprintf(Log,"%s%s",WSAGetLastError(),"\n");**
            fprintf(Log,"%s%s","ERROR writing to STATS","\n");
            fprintf(Log,"%d%s",n,"\n");
            fflush(Log);
            error("ERROR writing to STATS");
        }
```

In this the following is happening:
1. server reads a line and sends to client
2. client reads the line and sends back the acknowledgement back to server
3. this process happens successfully to some tests
4. after some time the while sending back acknowledgement to server through send command, it returns WSAECONNABORTED (10053)

I don't know what is the reason.

Please help

Thanks,
Pankaj

Comment: I found out this explanation of the error at microsoft web in spanish http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925513/es, it tolds it's a known error. And it have a hotfix. You can check it here in spanish too http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931319

Comment: the link which you shared is for win2003. I'm on win7 64-bit